# Finding the Nth term of Fibonacci for very large N

Tags: java, fibonacci, largenumber

I have used the iterative method as well as the recursion method but in both cases I am not getting the result of fibo(10^6) faster ie. with O(logN) complexity.

Iterative method:

```
static BigInteger fibo(long n){
    BigInteger a=new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger b=new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger c=new BigInteger("0");
    for(long i=3;i<=n;i++){
        c=a.add(b);
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: This method of iteration is producing result upto 10^5 and stops at 10^6.

Comment: I have taken cases for n<=2 so no need to worry about that.Just want to know the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Closed form to only compute the `n`th value:

[image: closed form fibonacci formula]

You can read more about the topic (including this formula) on [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Unfortunately, you cannot use `BigInteger` here, but I think you should be able to do that with a `BigDecimal` (I haven't tested that, though).

Comment: @Michael Okay, true if you account for the fact that `x^n` won't be a constant-time operation for giant numbers. Maybe depends on how you see `exp(x)` and `ln(x)`. But it's definitely in `O(log n)`. I've correced my answer.

Comment: BigInteger or BigDecimal datz OK.That does not make any difference.The above formula given does not work for n>79.

Comment: @SourabhBanerjee works for all values of n.  You can't use `double`, you have to use `BigDecimal`

Comment: No the time limit is exceeding in case of 10^6 even after using BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the value of *fib(n)* for large n, you need to use the **Matrix Exponentiation Method** i.e. the one used for solving linear recurrence equations.

The great advantage of matrix exponentiation is that its running time is simply O(k^3 * logN) where N is the power of the matrix we are calculating and k is the size of the matrix.

*Check the below mentioned python code snippets which calculates fibonacci for large n (mods with 10^9+7, to have the number in int range).* You can find the detailed explanation of the same in [this](http://fusharblog.com/solving-linear-recurrence-for-programming-contest/) blog.

*matrix_mult* function multiplies the two matrices given as argument and returns their product.

```
def matrix_mult(A, B):
    C = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            for k in range(2):
                C[i][k] = (C[i][k] + (A[i][j]*B[j [k])%mod)%mod
return C
```

*fast_expo* function calculates and returns (matrix^power) and this is the function responsible for O(logn) running time.

```
def fast_expo(matrix, power):
    if(power==1):
        return matrix
    else:
        if(power%2==0):
            matrix1 = fast_expo(matrix, power/2)
            return matrix_mult(matrix1, matrix1)
        else:
            return matrix_mult(matrix, fast_expo(matrix, power-1))
```

The function is called with the precomputed matrix as one of the parameter. In the case of fibonacci, the matrix is [[1, 1], [1, 0]].

```
matrix = [[1, 1], [1, 0]]
matrix_n = fast_exponentiation(matrix, number-2)
print (matrix_n[0][0] + matrix_n[0][1]) % 1000000007
```

That power here should be M^(n-2) for all n>2 where M is the base Matrix, because you already have the first 2 values of f(n) i.e. f(1) and f(2).